# Oracle: excluding updates of one column for firing a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

In oracle I can specify the columns, which should induce a firing of a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger
before update of col1, col2, col3 on my_table for each row
begin
  // the trigger code will be executed only if col1 or col2 or col3 was updated
end;
```

*Now I want to do the following: I don't want the trigger to fire, when **only one** column was updated. How is this possible?*

I could list all columns except the one, which should not induce a firing of the trigger. This is quite cumbersome for tables with many columns.

Another way would be to use the UPDATING function like this:

```
if not updating('COL3') then ...
```

But if I changed COL1 *and* COL3 at once, the statement evaluates to false. That's not what I want since, I want to restrict the execution when **only one** column (COL3) was updated.

Comment: It's less cumbersome to list all the columns using the data dictionary. `SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE' AND column_name != 'COL3';`

Comment: That true, but someone else will need to maintain the trigger. If we would add a new column or rename it ... I already can hear him exclaming aloud. I would like to find a reliable way with less pain for him and especially me. ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
create or replace trigger my_trigger
before update on my_table
for each row
declare
   n_cols integer := 0;
begin
   for r in (select column_name from all_tab_columns
             where table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
             and owner = 'MY_SCHEMA')
   loop
      if updating(r.column_name) then
         n_cols := n_cols + 1;
         exit when n_cols > 1;
      end if;
   end loop;
   if n_cols > 1 then
      do_something;
   end if;
end;
```

Probably not terribly efficient though!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem yesterday.
I wanted to code a trigger that fired on every field except one, the table had 103 colums.

First I coded:

```
if (:OLD.col1<>:NEW.col1 or :OLD.col2<>:NEW.col2 or :OLD.col3<>:NEW.col3 ....)
```

But I had some problems with null values, so I added:

```
if (NVL(:OLD.col1,0)<>NVL(:NEW.col1,0) or NVL(:OLD.col2,0)<>NVL(:NEW.col2,0)  ....)
```

But then I had some problems with DATE columns, it became a mess..

I think that the best solution is to list all columns that you want to verify in the "OF":

```
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE of cOL1, col2, col3 ... colN ON table1
```

It was not "elegant" but... it worked perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably not the answer you want to hear, but I think you are rather over-exaggerating the burden of maintenance.  It is not normal for a table's structure to change very often after it goes into production.  If you do have a table which is subject to frequent changes of column number or name, then I would suggest you have a bigger, architectural problem.

So, just type out all the column names now, and wait to see whether maintanance becomes an issue.  It is certainly not worth coding a complicated implementation in a trigger - a tax which you will pay on every single update - in order to avoid an occasional changes to the DDL script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way you can avoid having to list all of the other columns in the table, either in the trigger body or else in the `before update of ...` clause.

However, you might be able to write an alter trigger on the table to regenerate the update trigger automatically if any columns are added or removed.  It's a little more work, but then the maintenance should be automatic.