# Need Column name , old value and new value in Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

Our requirement is if any 1 of the column name in table is updating we need to insert the column name in another table so I had written this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Test AFTER
  UPDATE ON XX_table
   FOR EACH Row 
   BEGIN FOR C IN
    (SELECT column_name
    FROM User_Tab_Columns
    WHERE Upper(Table_Name) = 'XX_table_name'    ORDER BY column_id ASC) 
    LOOP 
    IF Updating (c.column_name) 
    THEN
    INSERT INTO Xx_Trigger_table    (Rt_Id ,Updated_Column ,updated_status) VALUES(:Old.Rt_Id,C.Column_Name,'Y');
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Now Client need Old value as well as new value in the XX_Trigger_Table.I cant Write

```
INSERT INTO Xx_Trigger_table    (Rt_Id ,Updated_Column ,updated_status,old_value, new_value) VALUES(:Old.Rt_Id,C.Column_Name,'Y',:old.c.column_name,:new.c.column_name);
```

Please suggest me some idea to insert new and old value in the table.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is a weird requirement. Why would you need a **`column name`** in an audit table? All you would like to have the modified rows to be inserted into the audit table with a **`timestamp`** column.

Comment: Ya It's a Weird requirement by client.
But we need column name for some other transaction purpose.
It would be great if u can help me.

Comment: Then tell the client what it is not a good design. For auditing, there are many newer methods. **`Fine Grained Auditing`** is one good feature. Else, the old trigger approach should be implemented the way I have suggested. You need a audit table, with all the columns similar to the base table, with additional columns like, an id column as PK, an identifier column to know if it was an **`insert, update or delete`**,  and a **`timestamp`** column.

Comment: You can't refer to the column name in the new/old pseudorows dynamically like that (I'm surprised the updating clause allows it, really). If you're determined to have this audit structure then you would have to test each column name explicitly and individually, rather than in a loop, which means you list every column name. You could *create* the trigger code dynamically from the data dictionary if you're worried about the number of columns. Also note that `updating` means the column is referenced, not necessarily that the value actually changed.

Comment: As an alternative, [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11263792/266304) shows a way to use the more common audit table/trigger method, with an `unpivot` to see the changed values; you could do something similar, perhaps in a view, to satisfy the client requirement, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following this approach , like @Alex Poole suggested you will have to include all the columns that you would like to log. Please see this procedure and the output of it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Test1 AFTER
  UPDATE ON TESTEMP
   FOR EACH Row 
   BEGIN FOR C IN
    (SELECT column_name
    FROM User_Tab_Columns
    WHERE Upper(Table_Name) = 'TESTEMP'    ORDER BY column_id ASC) 
    LOOP 
    IF Updating (c.column_name)  then
    IF (c.column_name='EMPNO') then
    INSERT INTO test_audit    (col_name,old_val,new_val,upd_stat) VALUES (C.column_name,:Old.empno,:New.empno,'Y');
    ELSIF
    (c.column_name='ENAME') then
    INSERT INTO test_audit    (col_name,old_val,new_val,upd_stat) VALUES (C.column_name,:Old.ENAME,:New.ENAME,'Y');
    ELSIF
    (c.column_name='MGR') then
    INSERT INTO test_audit    (col_name,old_val,new_val,upd_stat) VALUES (C.column_name,:Old.MGR,:New.MGR,'Y');
    END IF;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END;



SQL> select * from testemp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20


SQL> select * from test_audit;

no rows selected

SQL> update testemp set empno=6677 , ename='JUPITER' where empno=1234;

1 row updated.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test_audit;

COL_NAME   OLD_VAL    NEW_VAL    U
---------- ---------- ---------- -
EMPNO      1234       6677       Y
ENAME      SMITH      JUPITER    Y
```

Comment: Anudeepks the issue with the above code is if we make any changes to table then we have to make changes in trigger also.

Comment: Yes, but how often is the table structure going to change?